# Assigning scalars from a subroutine which returns an array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a Perl subroutine which returns an array of vaules, and I'd like to call that subroutine and capture those values in individual scalar variables.

I know how to do this when initializing a group of scalars:

```
my ($workBenchId, $woId, $woTrayId, $trayId, $customerNumber) = SubRoutineA();
```

But I'm not sure how to do it with that same set of scalars (since I can't use 'my' again):

```
($workBenchId, $woId, $woTrayId, $trayId, $customerNumber) = SubRoutineA();
```

Thanks for your help - I'm new at Perl.

Comment: That would be the way to do it. This seems like something you could have very easily checked yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you can first just define your variables and later use them without `my`:

```
my ($workBenchId, $woId, $woTrayId, $trayId, $customerNumber);
...
($workBenchId, $woId, $woTrayId, $trayId, $customerNumber) = SubRoutineA(); 
...
($workBenchId, $woId, $woTrayId, $trayId, $customerNumber) = SubRoutineA(); 
...
($workBenchId, $woId, $woTrayId, $trayId, $customerNumber) = SubRoutineA();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have it exactly right.

```
($workBenchId, $woId, $woTrayId, $trayId, $customerNumber) = SubRoutineA();
```

Was that not appearing to work?